# How To extract words in a python string

Tags: python, string, extract, cpu-word

I have a lot of strings that look like the following:

```
Einwohnerzahl

244.951

StudierendeamHochschulort
[...]
```

The words are separated now by "\n". 
How can I seperated the whole words and numbers in separate lists? Because I got a lot of these strings which are not exactly the same I'am looking for a solution which can handele variations like different positions of the words / numbers or missing words / numbers in the string.

---

Final Solution:

In a first step I use

```
cleaned_string = re.sub('['+string.punctuation+']', '', cleanstring).split()
```

which generates the following output:

```
print(cleaned_string)
['Einwohnerzahl', '244951', 'StudierendeamHochschulort', '57573', 'Studierendenanteil']
```

After that I'am using

```
_re_digits = re.compile(r"(-?(?:(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?)|(?:\.\d+)))")
pure_zahlen = []
for element in cleaned_string:
    pure_zahlen += [ float(n) for n in _re_digits.findall(element)]
```

and

```
pure_text = [x for x in cleaned_string if not (x.isdigit() or x[0] == '-' and x[1:].isdigit())]
```

to seperate the text and the numbers from the list cleaned_string.

That gives me

```
print(pure_zahlen)
[41532.0, 2902.0, 70.0, 3739.0, 151319.0]
```

and

```
print(pure_text)
['Einwohnerzahl', 'StudierendeamHochschulort', 'Studierendenanteil']
```

Comment: Please add your attempt to the question and explain in detail where you got stuck. If your code throws an exception, please include the full error stack. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can just use the `split`method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have the string `myString`, Here, is how you can achieve your goal:

```
myString = """Einwohnerzahl

244.951

StudierendeamHochschulort"""


results  = [i.strip() for i in myString.split("\n") if i != '']

print(results)
```

> **Output**

```
['Einwohnerzahl', '244.951', 'StudierendeamHochschulort']
```

Comment: This solution works fine for my problem. Thank you!
Yesterday there was a post here that linked me to the re package. There I found this method: 
cleaned_string = re.sub('['+string.punctuation+']', '', cleanstring).split() 
This generates the same output as your solution does.
    print(cleaned_string)

Comment: Happy to know that my solution answers your problem. Yes, another way is to use `regular expression` with the module `re` .... My solution is very simple and easy to understand. I use a `list comprehension`....

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```py
s = 'apple\nbanana' #any phrase that you like
print(s.split('\n'))
```

Output:

```py
['apple', 'banana']
```

If you want it as separate words/phrases:

```py
s = 'apple\nbanana' 
for i in s.split('\n'):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
apple
banana
```

Comment: Thank you for your post, but split does not work so good. It results in: "['', '', 'Einwohnerzahl', '', '', '', '244.951', '', '', '', '', 'StudierendeamHochschulort'"

Comment: @Pablo What is your string exactly? I will try it and check. For the above mentioned string, my output is as expected.